# glib hash function for binary data

Tags: c, glib

I am trying to use glib to build a hash table, the keys will be some binary strings.

I can't use the builtin function `g_str_hash ()` since it's for C string (null terminated).  Can't use  the builtin function `g_direct_hash ()` either since it took just a pointer. There is a no way to specify the length of the key, that's why I can't provide my own version of hash function either (since it will take two parameters: a pointer to key and length to produce a hash,  what is against the function pointer type GHashFunc).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you wrap the binary data in a structure that contains a pointer to the data as well as its length? Then use that structure instead of the raw binary data pointer.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. It involves some extra work on memory operation, but this is a good workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Use [g_bytes_new](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html#g-bytes-new) (or similar) to put your data and length into a [GBytes struct](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html#GBytes) and use the provided [g_bytes_hash()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html#g-bytes-hash) and [g_bytes_equal()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html#g-bytes-equal) to [initialize the hash table](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-new).

> A GBytes can come from many different origins that may have different procedures for freeing the memory region. Examples are memory from g_malloc(), from memory slices, from a GMappedFile or memory from other allocators.
>
> GBytes work well as keys in GHashTable. Use g_bytes_equal() and g_bytes_hash() as parameters to g_hash_table_new() or g_hash_table_new_full(). GBytes can also be used as keys in a GTree by passing the g_bytes_compare() function to g_tree_new().

If your data is fixed width and the extra memory bothers you, you can write your own [GHashFunc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#GHashFunc) and [GEqualFunc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#GEqualFunc) as thin wrappers which temporarily put your data into a GBytes struct in order to use g_bytes_hash() and g_bytes_equal().